# Angularjs models not binding to json template used in http post request

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a static/variable json request template of sorts that I'm using when sending a $http POST request from a controller via a $http post factory. The problem is that model data, which is in scope in devtools, does not pass along with the rest of the template. Example is below. Any amazing insights would be... well amazing.

```
var a = 'a';
var b = $scope.b;
var c = $scope.c;

$rootScope.requestData = 
    [
        {
            "key": a, // Binds on submission = I'm happy
            "key": b, // Does not bind on submission = I'm angry
            "key": $rootScope.b, // Does not bind on submission = I'm angry
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Where are a, b, c defined? Also i am not even sure if the json format for requestData is correct. Did you imply [{key:a},{key:b}....]?

Comment: "$scope.b" and "$scope.c" correspond to model data entered into form inputs while "a" is a static value hard coded, which may or may not get a form input in the near future. The dynamic values from $scope fail to populate their corresponding values in the json template. The hard coded variable "a", passes and populates the template without issue. The primary question I have is why would hard coded variables pass and $scoped variables fail?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use the $rootScope always. Scopes in angular follow prototypical inheritance , so you should be able to access the parent scope attributes from the child scope   (This happens for all cases except in directives where an isolated scope can be created).

Can you instead using the child scope itself, but reference the elements in the parent scope. You might want to check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/56465) for better understanding.